# Un cocu, une … et un … : Comment s'appellent les autres personnes dans une telle situation (de cocu)?

Tags: expressions, langage-des-jeunes

Une situation de cocu est une situation dont la femme fait son mari cocu.
Mes questions sont les suivantes. **Comment designons-nous les autres personnages?**

- l'homme qui fait l'amour à la femme qui fait son mari cocu
- la femme qui fait son mari cocu

Je voudrais également savoir s'il y a des désignations au cas où les rôles sont inversés. C'est-à-dire:

- un homme qui triche sa femme
- la femme qui fait l'amour à l'homme qui triche sa femme
- la femme trichée

*Si possible, mentionner dans la réponse si le mot est considéré soutenu ou familier.*

Comment: [cocu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocu) : *"Personne dont le partenaire ou le conjoint est infidèle."*. C'est donc autant masculin que féminin.

Comment: Tu es sûr? "Sylvie est une cocu?"

Comment: Oui, le [dictionnaire Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cocu_cocue/16875) met un *'e'* pour le féminin. Note par ailleurs que "cocu" appartient au registre familier.

Comment: On utilise le verbe _tromper_, plutôt que _tricher_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Le mari infidèle / volage
- La femme trompée
- La maîtresse

---

- Le mari trompé (familier: le cocu)
- La femme infidèle / volage / adultère (vieilli)
- L'amant

Note: « Cocue » existe au féminin mais son emploi, en progression, reste [beaucoup plus rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cocu%2Ccocue&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccocu%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcocu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCocu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOCU%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccocue%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcocue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCocue%3B%2Cc0) que celui de « cocu ».

Comment: Ça serait parfait si tu pouvais ajouter [cocue](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cocu_cocue/16875) !

Comment: @YohannV. Note ajoutée.

Comment: ça s'emploie aussi dans le langage courant.Il t'a fait cocue?

Comment: @Quidam Oui, bien sûr. *Faire cocu* s'emploie au féminin aussi. *Il t'a faite cocue* pour certains puristes...

Comment: Oui, dans le langage de tous les jours c'est "il t'a fait cocue". Je n'ai jamais entendu la version plus correcte et soutenue. On voit peu le mot "cocue" écrit au féminin. Mais dire qu'il n'existe pas en français, ou est rare, non, pas plus que sa version masculine. La version masculine a plus de notoriété grâce au théâtre (Feydeau par ex). Quant à cocufier, c'est aussi un terme utilisé, ce en quoi je m'inscris en faux par rapport à la réponse donnée juste au-dessous.

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai mis un point d'interrogation à mon commentaire du dessus, probablement que j'ai tapé trop vite, ou que je voulais le dire avec un ton "?!".

Comment: @Quidam J'ai du mal à comprendre le problème que tu as avec *cocufier* et la réponse donnée "juste au-dessous", puisqu'elle dit la même chose que toi.

Answer (score 5):

La désignation habituelle :

> *Le mari est cocu et la femme est trompée*.

En France, on n'emploie pas *tricher*  mais *tromper* ou *cocufier*.

Il n'y a pas de nom couramment employé dans les cas de vengeance, mais de nombreuses situations et personnages de théâtre, vaudeville ou tragédie.

Les relations définies par *[le triolisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triolisme)*  induisent le consentement des participants, ce qui n'est pas le cas des situations évoquées.

---

***EDIT***

Les mots *amant* et *amante* ne signifie pas forcément tromperie, mais ils peuvent être utilisés pour désigner les personnages de la question (n'ayant pas su insérer un tableau, les correspondances homme/femme selon les contextes se repèrent entre les ' / ').

Il faut donc préciser le contexte :

> Il est devenu l'amant de la femme de l'amant de sa femme.

On peut aussi imaginer, si sa femme le trompe avec un bisexuel, et qu'il le soit aussi :

> Il est devenu l'amant de l'amant de sa femme.

*Amant :* 
Sigisbée, soupirant, tourtereau, galant / gigolo /
mec, amoureux, chéri, mari, godelureau /
concubin, époux, compagnon.
Jules (soit mon Homme pour une femme, mais il a aussi le sens de maquereau), micheton (client d’une prostituée).

*Amante :*
Amie, amoureuse, bien-aimée, dulcinée, compagne / mondaine, demi mondaine /  nana, camarade femme, copine, maîtresse / concubine, régulière, épouse.
Poule (d'un Jules), régulière.

Comment: On peut aussi utiliser le verbe «cocufier» pour «tromper»

Comment: @BernardMassé J'ai inclus votre commentaire dans ma réponse, merci.

Comment: Bien sûr que si on emploie cocufier! Et une cocue!!  (elle est cocue, il m'a fait cocue). Absolument pas d'accord avec cette réponse. ça me semble arbitraire.

Comment: Il m'échappe aussi, j'ai lu trop vite. C'est ça de surfer à 4 heures du mat. Par contre, "Le mari est cocu et la femme est trompée.": les deux sont cocus. Et les deux sont trompés.

Comment: Non, vote pas négatif maintenu. Je venais justement pour l'enlever, pas eu le temps hier.

Comment: Pourrais-tu me rendre un service, étant donné que c'est ma très grande faute, édite ton message, d'une manière inutile, mais juste pour que je puisse revoter, je te dois bien ça. Et entre parenthèse, ça prouve ce que je dis tout le temps. Quand on met un downvote, il faut TOUJOURS laisser un message pour expliquer pourquoi, ça permet à la personne de corriger, ou à soi de changer d'avis quand on s'est trompé. C'est dommage que ce ne soit pas du tout la mentalité sur ce forum.

Comment: J'upvote tout en maintenant la restriction suivante (parce que je suis une grosse tatillonne): je ne suis pas d'accord avec "cocu", "cocue", mais d'accord avec tout le reste.

Comment: @Quidam — Le second Jules avais un ***j*** minuscule — Quand au·x cocu·e·s, on les laissera… MAGNIFIQUE·S !… À chacun ses cornes.